# Agrupar [group by] SQL Firebird

Tags: sql, select, firebird, group-by

Gostaria de saber se há como eu fazer uma consulta onde eu posso trazer campos que não estejam no meu `group by`.

Eu tenho o seguinte código:

```
select sum(TAB_FATURAMENTO.vl_item),CLIENTE.insc_cnpj
from TAB_FATURAMENTO
inner join (IMP_PROCESSO
  inner join CLIENTE
  on IMP_PROCESSO.cd_cliente = CLIENTE.codigo)
on TAB_FATURAMENTO.cd_processo = IMP_PROCESSO.cd_processo
where TAB_FATURAMENTO.cd_cliente like '%'
and TAB_FATURAMENTO.pg='S'
group by CLIENTE.insc_cnpj
```

No meu `select` gostaria de trazer mais dois campos, porém o agrupamento quero que fique somente pelo CNPJ dos clientes.

Comment: Quais campos? Seria valores diferentes dentro do mesmo cliente?

Comment: Sim, seriam valores diferente, @RovannLinhalis. No caso, tenho clientes com dois CNPJ's com a mesma razão, com endereços distintos, assim como o contrário.

Comment: não vejo problema, já tentou colocar `sum(X), cnpj, razao, endereco` com group by ` cnpj, razao, endereco` acredito que será da forma que precisa

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Desde já agradeço à ajuda de todos.

Em conversa com um colega de trabalho, explanei meu problema e o mesmo me deu a seguinte sugestão:

> Fazer o `select` do jeito que o mesmo esta, e na própria página php realizar um outro `select` trazendo as demais informações que eu preciso.

O mesmo ainda me sugeriu realizar este segundo `select` dentro de um `for`, assim a consulta se torna mais rápida.

```
<?php
    $tl_saldo = 0;
    if($_SESSION['saldo'] <> ""){
       $tl_saldo = count($_SESSION['saldo']);
    }
?>
<table width='100%' border='1'>
  <tr align='center' bgcolor='#999'>
    <td>CLIENTE</td>
    <td>CNPJ</td>
    <td>VL DESPESA</td>
  </tr>
<?php
    for($i = 0; $i < $tl_saldo; $i++){
        $obj_cnpj = $obj_pdo->getCnpj($_SESSION['saldo'][$i]->INSC_CNPJ);
        $_SESSION['cnpj'] = $obj_cnpj;
?>
  <tr align='center'>
    <td class='texto' style='text-align:left;text-indent:10px;'> print substr($_SESSION['cnpj'][0]->NOME,0,18); </td>
    <td class='texto'> print $_SESSION['saldo'][$i]->INSC_CNPJ; </td>
    <td class='texto'> print number_format($_SESSION['saldo'][$i]->SUM,"2",",","."); </td>
  </tr>
<?php
    }
?>
</table>
```

Comment: Cara, nem precisava de tudo isso. Como a coluna que ver quer mostrar é co cnpj/cpf do cliente, nome do cliente e o valor. Pode por no group by as outras colunas e depois sum no valor. Vai dar certo da mesma forma.

Comment: @MarcosMarques, o problema é que antes de assumirmos este banco, o mesmo era gerenciado por um terceiro e este deixou aberto aos usuário a parte de cadastro, sendo assim temos cadastros de clientes com o mesmo CNPJ com nomes distintos (porém quase semelhantes). Por isso tivemos esse trabalho todo. Apesar de tudo o mesmo funcionou muito bem.

Answer (score 1):

Dá sim, mas só se você usar funções agregadas nesses valores que você quer retornar, tipo sum(),count(),max() e etcs.